# Variable of array which holds objects conform to protocol with associated type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, associated-types

I am trying to build my own `Form` builder. It was going well until the point when I wanted to get a `Value` from a `Cell`. I wanted to make it generic as possible, for instance some `Cell`s could be responsible of `ValueType` of `Int` and others could be `String`.

Anyways, my all `Cell`s basically conforms to protocol called `BaseCell`. I assigned a `associatedType` to this protocol and added a variable `value` which would return different types for each `Cell`. After some tryings I come with with the following code which was thrown `Protocol 'BaseCell' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` four different places, two of them being functions, I changed the functions to be generic to protocols `associatedType` and it now throws the error two places.

```
protocol BaseCell where Self: UITableViewCell {
    associatedtype ValueType
    var value: ValueType { get }
}

class FieldCell: UITableViewCell, BaseCell {
    typealias ValueType = String
    var field : UITextField = { return UITextField() }()
    var value: String {
        return self.field.text ?? String()
    }
}
```

I even tried to make these `Section` and `Form` to be generics, however it led `cells` variable to one type of subclass of `BaseCell`. Whole point of `Section` struct is to hold different kind `Cell`s that will be in a `Section` of `UITableView`.

```
struct Section {
    //throws "Protocol 'BaseCell' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"
    var cells: [BaseCell] = []
    
    //it was throwing same error above however after applying generics, it has gone away
    mutating func append<T: BaseCell>(_ cell: T) {
        self.cells.append(cell)
    }
}
```

And class of `Form` is basically holds array of `Sections` to represented in the UI and I use its methods to ease up the building the `UITableView` and usage of it delegates.

```
class Form {
    
    private var sections: [Section] = [Section]()
    
    subscript(_ section: Int) -> Section {
        get {
            return self.sections[section]
        }
    }
    
    //throws "Protocol 'BaseCell' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"
    subscript(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> BaseCell {
        get{
            return self.sections[indexPath.section].cells[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    func section(_ section: Section = Section()) -> Form {
        self.sections.append(section)
        return self
    }
    
    //it was throwing same error above however after applying generics, it has gone away
    @discardableResult
    func cell<T: BaseCell>(_ cell: T) -> Form {
        self.sections.indices.last.map { self.sections[$0].cells.append(cell) }
        return self
    }
}
```

Final reminder here is I thought using `Type Erasure` to somehow get around this issue, again however, It would not be the best as another point of this attempt is to not have to make any castings. I just want to build a form using `UITableView` as this simple and it was working before the `associatedType` thing. Here a piece of code from the project.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //optional
    return self.form[indexPath]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //optional
    return self.form[indexPath].height
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the last comment, This how `Form` class actually looks like in the project.

```
class Form {
    
    private var sections: [Section] = [Section]()
    
    subscript(_ section: Int) -> Section {
        get {
            return self.sections[section]
        }
    }
    
    subscript(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> BaseCell {
        get{
            return self.sections[indexPath.section].cells[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfRows(inSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.sections[section].cells.count
    }
    
    func numberOfSections() -> Int {
        self.sections.count
    }
    
    func titleForHeader(inSection section: Int) -> String {
        self.sections[section].header
    }
    
    func titleForFooter(inSection section: Int) -> String {
        self.sections[section].footer
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    func section(_ section: Section = Section()) -> Form {
        self.sections.append(section)
        return self
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    func cell<T: BaseCell>(_ cell: T) -> Form {
        self.sections.indices.last.map { self.sections[$0].cells.append(cell) }
        return self
    }
}
```

And I use an instance of `Form` in `FormViewController: UITableViewController` to easily build up a `UITableView` as such,

```
class FormViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var form: Form = Form()
    
    override func loadView() {
        self.tableView = UITableView(style: .grouped)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
        
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        //optional self.form.sections
        return self.form.numberOfSections()
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //optional
        return self.form.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.form.titleForHeader(inSection: section)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.form.titleForFooter(inSection: section)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //optional
        // And at this part returns any kind of `Cell` that conforms to `BaseCell` and `UITableViewCell` based on the `indexPath` 
        return self.form[indexPath]
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        //optional
        return self.form[indexPath].height
    }
}
```

Finally in a `ViewController` I plan to use different types of `Cell`s, as the app heavily depends on `Form`s and those `Cell`s could be responsible for `name` and `surname` as `String` and others examples which can be `Int`, `Double`, `Date` or custom enum value.

```
class ViewController: FormViewController {
    
    var fieldCell: FieldCell = {
        let cell = FieldCell()
        return cell
    }()
    
    var buttonCell: ButtonCell = {
        let cell = ButtonCell()
        return cell
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.form
            .section()
            .cell(fieldCell)
            .cell(buttonCell)

    }
    
    func doStuff() {
        fieldCell.value // I expect String here
        buttonCell.value // I know buttoncell does not make sense but lets say I expect Int here
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably know that this error basically means that as soon as you have a protocol with associated value, it cannot be used as a normal protocol (e.g. having an array of those). Type erasure is likely the way to go.

Comment: Without seeing a bit more of your code it's hard to know what's the best solution here; it depends on how you're planning to use `BaseCell` in a generic context. So far the code you've posted doesn't need to use a protocol with associated type at all; where do you make use of that functionality?

Comment: So I have updated the question, giving pretty much all code at this point other than some custom `Cell` classes. @NobodyNada

Comment: And I know Type erasure is an option here however I believe there must be some other elegant way to achieve this. It does not necessarily be `associatedType` protocols. @NewDev